# Intellitrace 11 and Desktop app

Tags: debugging, intellitrace

I try to debug my desktop application via Intellitrace 11. But i found only one manual about intellitrace 11 ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_diagnosingissues_topic2.aspx)), but here about debug web apps, wich hosting on IIS. All other manuals in web similary and all about debug web apps.

Is it possble to debug desctop application via intellitrace 11 (stand alone, without Test Managmer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the standalone IntelliTrace to collect desktop app is a supported scenario in Visual Studio 2012. The following post maybe what you are looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365.aspx#BKMK_Collect_Data_from_Executables

You'll be out of luck if you're using Visual Studio 2010.